# I do not understand the output I'm getting for this program.

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism, derived-class

Inheritance program for `class polygon` which is the base class and I created a derived class call rectangle. In my polygon base class I have a constructor and destructor and two `print` functions for area and perimeter. In my derived class I have a constructor and destructor and two `print` functions for area and perimeter and `calc area` and `calc perimeter` functions.
What I don't understand is the output I get when I run this program right now. The output I want is `area = 45 perimeter = 28`. I get this output when I use `rect_1.calcarea()` but want it using `rect_1.printarea()`.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class polygon 
{

protected:
    double area;
    double perimeter;
public:
    polygon(){}
    virtual ~polygon(){ }
    virtual double printarea() const { return area ;} 
    virtual double printperimeter() const { return perimeter ;}
};

class rectangle : public polygon
{

public:
    rectangle(double , double ) ;
    ~rectangle(){ }
    double calcarea() ;
    double calcperimeter() ;
    virtual double printarea() const { return area ;} 
    virtual double printperimeter() const { return perimeter ;}

private:
    double length;
    double width;
};

rectangle::rectangle(double l , double w) 
{
    length = l;
    width = w;
}

double rectangle::calcarea() 
{
    area = length*width;
    return area;
}

double rectangle::calcperimeter() 
{
    perimeter = length + width;
    perimeter = perimeter * 2;
    return perimeter;
}

void main ()
{
    rectangle rect_1 (9.0, 5.0);

    cout<<"The Area of Rect_1 is " <<rect_1.printarea() <<endl;
    cout<<"The Perimeter of Rect_1 is " <<rect_1.printperimeter() <<endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: Aside: http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main

Answer (score 2):

`printarea()` is just returning the value of the member variable `area`. You're a) not initialising it to anything and b) not calculating the area anywhere.

I'd hazard a guess that your output is either zero or garbage—depending on compiler options—because area is not initialised (i.e. given a value).

If you call `calcarea()` inside the rectangle's constructor, or in main after instantiating your instance of it, then `printarea()` would yield the correct value. You could even call `calcarea()` inside `printarea()` to be sure the value is always up to date when needed.

Comment: Or call `calcarea()` in `printarea()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution below. This will solve your problem.

Here is what I've changed:
I have made Polygon as abstract class, as you want to call only `printarea` or `printperimeter` of `Polygon`. Furthermore, I have called `calcarea` and `calcperimeter`, respectively. Although the same can be done in the body of `printarea`/`printperimeter` of `Rectangle`. There is no need to call `calcarea` and `calcperimeter`.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class polygon 
{

protected:
    double area;
    double perimeter;
public:
    polygon(){}
    virtual ~polygon(){ }
    virtual double printarea() = 0; 
    virtual double printperimeter() = 0;
};

class rectangle : public polygon
{

public:
    rectangle(double , double ) ;
    ~rectangle(){ }
    double calcarea() ;
    double calcperimeter() ;
    double printarea()  { return calcarea();} 
    double printperimeter() { return calcperimeter() ;}

private:
    double length;
    double width;
};

rectangle::rectangle(double l , double w) 
{
    length = l;
    width = w;
}

double rectangle::calcarea() 
{
    area = length*width;
    return area;
}

double rectangle::calcperimeter() 
{
    perimeter = length + width;
    perimeter = perimeter * 2;
    return perimeter;
}

void main ()
{
    rectangle rect_1 (9.0, 5.0);

    cout<<"The Area of Rect_1 is " <<rect_1.printarea() <<endl;
    cout<<"The Perimeter of Rect_1 is " <<rect_1.printperimeter() <<endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What have you changed? What was the problem?

Comment: I have made Polygon as abstract class. As he wants to call only printarea or printperimeter of polygon. Furhter I have called calcarea and calcperimeter respectively. Although same can be done in body of printarea/printperimeter of Rectangle. No need to call calcarea and calcperimeter.